# Google Maps URL parameter "pw=2" does not work anymore

Tags: google-maps, parameters

On our website, we have a store locator using Google Maps. Users can also plan a route to a store and print it. To open a print view, we used URL parameter `pw=2` successfully, but since a few days/weeks the param leads to a 404 page.

Example:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=74321&daddr=70378 works, whereas

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=74321&daddr=70378&pw=2 leads to a 404.

Does anybody know a workaround or a substitute for the `pw=2` param?

Comment: I'm not saying this is the best option... but user can do "Ctrl+p"